# Django selenium liveserver redirects to admin site

Tags: django, selenium, django-testing

I'm using django 1.3 with Django liveserver backported to 1.3. It worked fine, when i was doing tutorial from [Django LiverserverTestCase documentaion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase)
but with imports for django 1.3. It tests **"/admin/"** page and is ok, but when i try to test my urls, even just **"/"**, it goes to admin again! why? I didn't find any clues in Google, maybe this problem is only one.

Maybe i dissmissed some settings of the server.. But localhost:8000/test works fine after runserver command.

Answer if somebody had this type of problem.

```
from django_liveserver.testcases import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver

class MySeleniumTests(LiveServerTestCase):
fixtures = ['nstein/test-users.json']

@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.selenium = WebDriver()
    cls.selenium.implicitly_wait(3)
    super(MySeleniumTests, cls).setUpClass()

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    super(MySeleniumTests, cls).tearDownClass()
    cls.selenium.quit()

def test_login(self):

    self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url. '/admin/'))
    body = self.selenium.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
    self.assertIn('Username', body.text)
    username_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_id("id_username")
    password_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_id("id_password")
    password_input.send_keys('123')
    username_input.send_keys('admin')
    password_input.clear()
    self.selenium.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Log in"]').click()
    body = self.selenium.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
    self.assertIn('Site administration', body.text) 
    # url is in the urls.py of the app, 
    #selenium gets response 302 but redirects to /admin/
    self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url. '/test/'))
```

urls.py of the app:

```
#from cms import sitemaps
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from hitcount.views import update_hit_count_ajax
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

import dselector
from wcms.furniture_today.views import *

parser = dselector.Parser()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
parser.url(r'^test/$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'index.html'}, 'index'),
)
```

global urls:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from wcms.business.views import wcms_admin_redirect

urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
url(r'^', include('wcms.admin_urls')),
url(r'^', wcms_admin_redirect),
url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG: # assuming dev server
urlpatterns += patterns('', (r'^' + settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip('/'), include('appmedia.urls')))

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url. '/test/'))` in a new function

```
def test_two(self):
    self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url. '/test/'))
```